# String decompression : Reduce time and space complexity

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, compression

**N-rounds** of compression are run on a string, where each round replaces some character pattern with **one special character** (using a dictionary).

Given this compressed string and the dictionary used for compression, we need to find the original string.

#### For ex:

Dictionary used for compression:

*b12k* -> *?*

*a?l* -> *#*

*#mn* -> *!*

So, the string **ab12klmn** is compressed as **!**

**What data structure suits best to store this dictionary such that the decompression is O(n) operation with least possible extra space used?**

**What I've tried:**
This was an interview question, I stored the dictionary in a map with *target alphabet* (of the compression dictionary) as the key of my map and decompressed strings as the values.
Then a traversal through the given string replacing the special characters with their respective expansions.
For ex:

*!* -> *ab12klmn*

*#* -> *ab12k*

*?* -> *b12k*

Then to reduce the duplicacy of string patterns I did a tree like structuring of this dictionary but the interviewer wasn't satisfied.
Where can I improve this solution?

Comment: I tried doing this, this increases the space complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that we need to get back the original string from the given compressed string.

The best data structure that you can use here can be an 2-dimensional vector (dynamic array). I will try and explain why this can be the best data structure for this problem.

1. When we use a map we introduce a **logn** factor while looking for a particular key. With vectors if you know the location of your search query it can be done in **O(1)**.
2. When we use a vector we are not wasting any extra memory blocks. This is also the case with maps. But if you use 2-d arrays unnecessary memory will be wasted.

But since there are only 256 characters, we will store the dictionary as follows. Lets have a 2d vector of strings with max 256 rows. For this example

b12k -> ?

a?l -> #

#mn -> !

So we will store "b12k" at v[63] as ASCII value of '?' is 63. Similarly, we will store we will store "a?l" at v[35] as ASCII value of '#' is 35 and so on,

NOW HOW TO FIND THE ORIGINAL STRING:

We start from the compressed string.

1. Initialize your string which will store the final ans. Lets call it origString = "".
2. Start traversing the string. If its a non-special character add this character to the origString.
3. If we find any special character just go to that characters ASCII value and its corresponding location in 2d-vector.
4. Go to step 2.

The pseudo-code for this is

```
    origString = "";
    func getOriginalFromCompressed(string s) 
        for i = [0:s.length()-1]
            if(v[s[i]].length()) getOriginalFromCompressed(v[s[i]]);
            else                 origString = stringConcat(origString,s[i]);   //add the charcacter to your final ans
        end for
    end func
```

origString has the original string.

So the time and space complexity of this solution is O(n). 
where n=sum of lengths of all the strings in dictionary given.